# Failed to send data stream by sockets in Java

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, javasound

I'm trying to stream audio through `TCP` sockets in java, using the `Java sound api`.

Up there all right, the problem comes when the client will play that data buffer that comes from the server, when entering the play method, automatically shows the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException: could not get audio input stream from input stream
    at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(AudioSystem.java:1121)
    at AudioClient.play(AudioClient.java:37)
    at AudioClient.main(AudioClient.java:18)
```

I do not know why he shows it, or what I'm doing wrong.

This is the server code, which looks for the file and sends it to the client

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;



public class AudioServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File soundFile = AudioUtil.getSoundFile("C:\\Users\\Carlos\\Desktop\\03- Walk.wav");

        System.out.println("server: " + soundFile);

        try (ServerSocket serverSocker = new ServerSocket(6666); 
            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(soundFile)) {
            if (serverSocker.isBound()) {
                Socket client = serverSocker.accept();
                OutputStream out = client.getOutputStream();

                byte buffer[] = new byte[2048];
                int count;
                while ((count = in.read(buffer)) != -1)
                    out.write(buffer, 0, count);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("server: shutdown");
    }
}
```

And this is the client code, which captures that data flow and reproduces it

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;

public class AudioClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // play soundfile from server
        System.out.println("Client: reading from 192.168.0.19:6666");
        try (Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.0.19", 6666)) {
            if (socket.isConnected()) {
                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                play(in);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Client: end");
    }

    private static synchronized void play(final InputStream in) throws Exception {
        AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(in);
        try (Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip()) {
            clip.open(ais);
            clip.start();
            Thread.sleep(100); // given clip.drain a chance to start
            clip.drain();
        }
    }
}
```

Additionally, there is an `AudioUtils` class, which only contains a static method, this static method only throws an exception in case the file passed by the programmer is not a file or does not exist. The code is the following

```
import java.io.File;

public class AudioUtil {
    public static File getSoundFile(String fileName) {
        File soundFile = new File(fileName);
        if (!soundFile.exists() || !soundFile.isFile())
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("not a file: " + soundFile);
        return soundFile;
    }
}
```

It should also be clarified that both classes, both server and controller have the proncipal method because they are 2 separate programs. My question is, how do I solve this error, I really do not know where to start. Thank you

Comment: The `isBound()` and `isConnected()` tests are both pointless here. They cannot possibly return `false`. You never close the accepted socket in the server, so the client blocks forever trying to read.

Comment: And your `getSoundFile()` method is completely redundant. `new FileInputStream(...)` will already throw an exception if any of those conditions aren't met, and more.